# Determining how big an element will be in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, height

I need to position an element in the exact centre of the page (using fixed positioning) and need to calculate the expected size. For example I would add HTML like this:

```
<div class="window" style="left: X; top: Y">
    <h3 class="title">Title</h3>
    <img src="file.jpg" width="300" height="200" />
    <div class="controls">Some stuff</div>
</div>
```

The width will be the image width plus some padding. I want to determine what the height of the element will be by getting the styles from the stylesheet, then calculate the correct position, then write the HTML with the right styles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only tell once it's been added to the document (that is, you can't tell the *expected* size and you won't be able to do it server-side).

So, in Javascript, set the visibility to `hidden`, add it to the document, check its `outerHeight` or with jQuery call `$('.window').height()`, reposition as needed, and then change visibility back to `visible`.

...or, use this plugin:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $.fn.vCenter = function(options) {
        var empty = {},
            defaults = {
                allowNegative : false,
                relativeToBody : true
            },
            settings = $.extend(empty, defaults, options)
        ;

        var isVisible = this.is(":visible");
        if (!isVisible) {
            this.css({visibility : "hidden"}).show();
        }
        if (settings.relativeToBody && this.offsetParent().get(0).nodeName.toLowerCase() != "body") {
            this.appendTo(document.body);
        }
        var pos = {
            sTop : function() {
                return window.pageYOffset || $.boxModel && document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;
            },
            wHeight : function() {
                if ($.browser.opera || ($.browser.safari && parseInt($.browser.version, 10) > 520)) {
                    return window.innerHeight - (($(document).height() > window.innerHeight) ? getScrollbarWidth() : 0);
                } else if ($.browser.safari) {
                    return window.innerHeight;
                } else {
                    return $.boxModel && document.documentElement.clientHeight || document.body.clientHeight;
                }
            }
        };
        return this.each(function(index) {
            if (index === 0) {
                var $this = $(this),
                    $w = $(window),
                    topPos = ($w.height() - $this.height()) / 2 + $w.scrollTop()
                ;
                if (topPos < 0 && !settings.allowNegative) topPos = 0;

                $this.css({
                    position: 'absolute',
                    marginTop: '0',
                    top: topPos //pos.sTop() + (pos.wHeight() / 2) - (elHeight / 2)
                });
                if (!isVisible) {
                    $this.css({visibility : ""}).hide();
                }
            }
        });
    };
    $.fn.hCenter = function(options) {
        var empty = {},
            defaults = {
                allowNegative : false,
                relativeToBody : true
            },
            settings = $.extend(empty, defaults, options)
        ;

        if (settings.relativeToBody && this.offsetParent().get(0).nodeName.toLowerCase() != "body") {
            this.appendTo(document.body);
        }
        return this.each(function(index) {
            if (index === 0) {
                var $this = $(this),
                    $d = $(document),
                    leftPos = ($d.width() - $this.width()) / 2 + $d.scrollLeft()
                ;
                if (leftPos < 0 && !settings.allowNegative) leftPos = 0;
                $this.css({
                    position: "absolute",
                    left: leftPos
                });
            }
        });
    };
    $.fn.hvCenter = function(options) {
        return this.vCenter(options).hCenter(options);
    };
});
```

Usage:

```
$('.window').hvCenter();  // horizontal and vertical center
```

Answer (score 2):

With jQuery, you want to use the `outerHeight` and `outerWidth` functions.

Without jQuery, you want to use `offsetHeight` and `offsetWidth` DOM properties.

Note that these both include the padding and border in their calculations, whereas jQuery `height` and `width` do not. Optionally, `outerHeight` and `outerWidth` can be made to include margin, but `offsetHeight` and `offsetWidth` cannot.

Comment: But how do I get the values before inserting the element into the document?

Comment: Indeed you *cannot* do that. Reason being different documents can have different style rules. You can only measure a DOM element after it has been added to a DOM document. Additionally, its CSS `display` must be anything other than `none`, but its visibility can be `hidden`.

Comment: Actually, let me take that back. You certainly could do it, since standards-compliant browsers (and MSIE, via different properties) allow you to programatically access style sheet rules, but you would essentially have to write your own CSS parser to accomplish it.

Answer (score 0):

you can get width and height using `width()` and `height()`

so `$('.window').height()` will return the computed height of the element in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this [pure CSS way of centering an image in a box](http://www.brunildo.org/test/img_center.html)?

Answer (score -1):

You can use CSS:

```
.window {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Works exactly the same in IE6 as other browsers (in standards mode). But it doesn't do vertical height, which is the key here.